# the file is not arriving properly

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to send a file from the client to the server. But the articles in my file do not reach the server. How can i solve it ?

client side:

```
            f= open(filename,'rb')
            l = f.read(buf)
            while (l):
                client.sendto(l,ADDR)
                print('Sending\n ',repr(l))
                l = f.read(buf)
                f.close()
                print('Completed')
                client.close()
```

Server code:

```
        with open('recv.txt', 'wb') as f:
            while True:
                print('getting file...')
                pdata,addr = server.recvfrom(buf)
                print('data=%s', (pdata))
                if not pdata:
                    break
                # write data to a file
                f.write(pdata)

                f.close()
                print('Completed')
                server.close()
                print('Connection closed')
```

Comment: In both the server and client, you are closing the file inside the loop, before the full thing is sent. Move the `f.close` and the subsequent lines outside the `while` loop.

Comment: In the server you don't even need `f.close()` because you're inside a `with`.

Answer (score 0):

You already get explanation in comments - you have wrong indentations.

You have to close file after leaving `while` loop

```
f = open(filename, 'rb')
l = f.read(buf)

while l:
    client.sendto(l, ADDR)
    print('Sending\n', repr(l))
    l = f.read(buf)

# --- after loop ---

f.close()
print('Completed')
client.close()
```

And when you use `with` then you don't need `close()` because `with` will close it

```
with open('recv.txt', 'wb') as f:
    while True:
        print('getting file...')
        pdata, addr = server.recvfrom(buf)
        print('data=', pdata)
        if not pdata:
            break
        # write data to a file
        f.write(pdata)

# --- after loop ---

#f.close() # no need it
print('Completed')
server.close()
print('Connection closed')
```